# Artifacts on threejs

Tags: three.js

I'm developing a threejs application.
I need to reproduce a door, so it should be quite easy becouse it is just a Box geometry and a stl file for the handler.

The problem is that when I move the camera with the mouse, the render produces artifacts. Part of the models become trasparent and it is a very bad effect.

This is how the handler should be:
[image]

This is how it become moving the camera:
[image]

This my code:

```
//* Renderer
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas, antialias: true });
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);

//* Scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x1f1f1f);


    //* textures
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    this.doorTexure = textureLoader.load('./assets/3d/textures/steal.png');
    this.doorTexure.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    this.doorTexure.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    this.doorTexure.repeat.set(7, 7);

    this.handlerTexure = textureLoader.load('./assets/3d/textures/steal.png');


    //* Handler
    const loaderSTL = new STLLoader()
    loaderSTL.load('./assets/3d/test.stl', geometry => {
      this.handlerMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x222222, specular: 0xFFFFFF, shininess: 250, map: this.handlerTexure });
      this.handlerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.manigliaMaterial);
      this.handlerMesh.castShadow = true;
      this.handlerMesh.receiveShadow = true;

      this.scene.add(this.handlerMesh);
    });


    //* Door
    this.doorMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
    this.doorMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    this.scene.add(this.doorMesh);

    this.doorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: this.doorTexure });
    this.doorMesh.material = this.doorMaterial;



    //* Camera
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(1, this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 10000000);
    this.camera.position.x = 100;
    this.camera.position.y = 100;
    this.camera.position.z = 5000;


    //* Lights
    const light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5);
    light1.castShadow = true;
    light1.position.set(-10, 10, 12);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light1, 5));
    this.scene.add(light1);

    const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x999999, 1);
    light2.position.set(10, 10, 10);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light2));
    this.scene.add(light2);

    const light3 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x999999, 1);
    light3.position.set(10, 10, -10);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light3));
    this.scene.add(light3);


    //* Axes helper
    const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(30);
    this.scene.add(axesHelper);
```

And when the user changes the door width/height through a form, I do this to update the render:

```
    // Door
    this.doorMesh.geometry = new RoundedBoxGeometry(this.door.width / 10, this.door.height / 10, 2, 6, 0.21);
    this.doorMaterial.color = new THREE.Color(this.door.color);



    // Handler
    this.handlerMesh.scale.set(this.handler.width / 2500, this.hanlder.height / 2500, 0.05);
    this.handlerMesh.position.x = this.handler!.x / 100;
    this.handlerMesh.position.y = this.handler.y / 100;
    this.handlerMesh.position.z = 2;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using

```
mesh.depthWrite = false;
```